# Speeding up PowerShell script with Access database

Tags: performance, powershell, ms-access, ado

I have a script, which is basicly reading a csv file and searching related ms-access database records and updating them. Problem is its getting slower after 100-150 records. Can someone have an opinion about it. But please consider first records are fast implementing, thats why its strange issue for me. By the way script runs on local pc, not on server.

```ps
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = $path")
Write-Host "database connection established"

$data = Import-Csv $csvfile

$data =$data | Where-Object{$_.b}
$itemNo=0
$dp=1
$fp=1
$total=0

$Verkaufsbeleg=0
$Verkaufsbelegposition=0


foreach ($element in $data) {


              if($itemNo -ne $element.d + $element.f -and $element.d){                        
                   $itemNo=$element.d + $element.f

                   $Verkaufsbeleg=$element.d 

                   $Verkaufsbelegposition=$element.f 

                    $param1= [convert]::ToInt32($Verkaufsbeleg, 10)
                    $param2=[convert]::ToInt32($Verkaufsbelegposition, 10)

                    write-host $param1 
                    write-host $param2

                    $dp=0
                    $fp=0   
                    $position=99     


                }

                if($element.k -eq $something){
                   $dp++
                }elseif($element.k -eq $something){
                   $fp++
                }


               $rs.Open("Select * From Projects where ([Column1]='"+$param1+"' and [Column2]="+$param2+")", $cn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic) 


                 While ($rs.EOF -ne $True) {

                     $value=$element.i                  

                    if($element.k -eq $something){

                        $rs.Fields.Item("DP")=$value

                        $total++                                          
                    }
                    if($element.k -eq $something){

                        $rs.Fields.Item("FP")=$value

                        $total++                                         
                    }

                  write-host "Index"   $rs.AbsolutePosition

                  $rs.MoveNext()

                }      

                $rs.Close()      
                $rs= new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

} 


$cn.Close()
Write-Host "Total Items Updated" $total
```

Comment: You open rs once, then do your reading and looping, finally close rs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved. it is a bad decision this to make select statement with Open function. Taking all data in one time and filter it with RS.Filter will be totaly a solution.

$rs.Filter="[Column1]='"+$param1+"' and [Column2]="+$param2

after calculations and upgrades ir can be cleared by

$rs.Filter=0

Thanks